# Why pulseaudio is reported as not running?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I have `Ubuntu 21.10` and I get the below results related to `pulseaudio`.
What should I do to "connect" to `pulseaudio` such that `pacmd list-sinks` to correctly report something?

```bsh
$sudo netstat -tlupn | egrep -i "mopidy|pulse"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4713            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1730/pulseaudio
tcp6       0      0 :::4713                 :::*                    LISTEN      1730/pulseaudio

$pacmd list-sinks
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

$ps -ef | egrep "/[p]ulseaudio"
lightdm     1730    1668  0 Oct30 ?        00:04:35 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
```

**UPDATE**

```bsh
$systemctl --user --no-pager status pulseaudio
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-10-31 19:15:19 EET; 3min 27s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 1992370 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 37152)
     Memory: 1.7M
        CPU: 23ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─1992370 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Oct 31 19:15:18 adrhc.go.ro systemd[1510]: Starting Sound Service...
Oct 31 19:15:19 adrhc.go.ro systemd[1510]: Started Sound Service.

$systemctl --user --no-pager status pipewire
● pipewire.service - Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-10-30 23:39:22 EEST; 20h ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 1767 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 37152)
     Memory: 1.4M
        CPU: 139ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─1767 /usr/bin/pipewire

Oct 30 23:39:22 adrhc.go.ro systemd[1510]: Started Multimedia Service.
Oct 30 23:39:22 adrhc.go.ro pipewire[1767]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct 30 23:39:22 adrhc.go.ro pipewire[1767]: could not set nice-level to -11: Permission denied
Oct 30 23:39:23 adrhc.go.ro pipewire[1767]: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Oct 30 23:39:23 adrhc.go.ro pipewire[1767]: could not make thread realtime: Permission denied
```

**UPDATE**
I'm running the commands while connected with ssh from a remote location.

Comment: From the ps command, pulseaudio is running as the lightdm user, and thus probably not as the user typing these commands. Are you doing this remotely rather than from the local keyboard?

Comment: yes, I'm running the commands while connected with ssh from a remote location

Answer (score 2):

> Why pulseaudio is reported as not running?

Because pulse isn't running!

As far as I remember, Ubuntu made the switchover to pipewire with 21.10

Comment: Please reconsider your answer after seeing my `ps -ef | grep /[p]ulseaudio` output. Pulseaudio is started automatically with lightdm as you cand see in the post's logs.

Comment: yes, but that's just for lightdm to be able to play sounds, not for your user session.

Comment: the thing is that I have a systemd *system* service which is using pulseaudio to play music and is working so pulseaudio should be present too. Mopidy is not capable to use pipewire (I don't have pipewire-pulse package installed).

Comment: Maybe you have to install pipewire-pulse to be able to use pulseaudio clients in 21.10?